# What is a safe amount of juniper?

Tags: safety

I have some berries of [alpine juniper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juniperus_communis#Subspecies). I read that in big quantities they can be [toxic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juniper_berry#Toxicity). So for the moment I tried them in small amounts. Last time I took a couple of pinches, about ten berries, I crushed them I threw away the peels, mixed the rest with the food and cooked everything. I liked the taste, but it was faint, not very spicy.

Roughly how much juniper could I add to the food and still be on the safe side?

Comment: Some LD50 data in animals in these. Don't know how well that extrapolates to people. https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/mrl-report/juniperi-fructus-summary-report-committee-veterinary-medicinal-products_en.pdf ° https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/10915810160233758

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All juniper berries contain [thujone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thujone), which is the primary source of toxicity concern.  Thujone is psycoactive in minute quantities, but in larger ones is a convulsant and disruptor of the digestive system.  Different varieties of juniper have different concentrations of thujone and other chemicals (like sabinylacetate), resulting in vastly different levels of toxic risk (particularly, [Savin Juniper](https://www.latifasherbs.com/toxic-juniper/) is dangerous with just a few berries).

Alpine juniper are Juniperus communis, which is the "safe" variety usually used for culinary purposes.  So you're OK there.

Per the excellent scientific papers linked by @Ecnerwal, toxicity levels of Juniperus communis fruit (Juniperi fructus) are extremely low.  To quote the [veterinary paper](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/mrl-report/juniperi-fructus-summary-report-committee-veterinary-medicinal-products_en.pdf):

> the Committee for Veterinary Medicinal Products concludes that there is no need to establish an MRL [maximum residue limit] for Juniperi fructus

... in other words, toxicity is low enough that it's not worth establishing specific safe amounts.  For example, strong alimentary reactions in rats were observed only at a level of 0.5% juniper oil in food -- the equivalent of consuming a teaspoon of pure juniper essential oil in your meal.  Or, more to your question, *two US cups* of juniper berries.  Abortifacent reactions with Juniperus communis were even higher.

Similarly, US food authorities regard [Juniperi fructus as Generally Regarded as Safe](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/cfrsearch.cfm?fr=182.20), and do not establish specific amount limits.

So the overall question of "how many juniper berries is potentially toxic" is "more than you're going to be willing to eat".*

All that aside, the flavor of Juniper berries should be very strong.  I usually only add about 4-7 of them to a large pot of [rotkhol](https://thewanderlustkitchen.com/german-braised-red-cabbage-rotkohl/).  As such, if you're getting little flavor from 10 berries, it may be that you don't want to use these particular berries because they're just too bland.

(* caveat: you, personally, might have a specific allergy to juniper, which would lower the amounts that would provoke a reaction)